# Flutter Stateful Shell Route - Keep state of child routes with Go Router

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to reproduce Instagram UI and i'm working on conversation functionality. My routes look like this

```
|Home
|--Conversations
|----Conversation details
|--Home Details
|Search
|--Search Details
|Profile
|--My Profile
|--Configuration
```

When I go in Conversations then select a particular conversation (so I'm now in Conversation details) and begin to write a message (but do not send), I want it to be saved when i navigate to any other page. Like Instagram.

Any idea on how to keep state of a child route ?

Maybe I'm designing it wrong and should make Conversations as a new base Route like that ?

```
|Home
|--Home Details
|Conversations
|--Conversation details
|Search
|--Search Details
|Profile
|--My Profile
|--Configuration
```

But if I use this design I don't know how to get back to Home and restoring home state from Conversations (Conversation is the top right arrow button) :

[image: Conversation is the top right arrow button]

Code to reproduce :
https://github.com/xaoc2nd/StatefulShellRouteError/tree/main/lib/Home